# Ordering the x-axis in an R graph

Tags: r, graph

I have a data.frame that looks like:

```
          gvs order           labels
1  -2.3321916     1           Adygei
2  -1.4996229     5           Basque
3   1.7958170    15           French
4   2.5543214    19          Italian
5  -2.7758460    33         Orcadian
6  -1.9659984    39          Russian
7   2.1239768    41        Sardinian
8  -1.8515908    47           Tuscan
9  -1.5597359     6          Bedouin
10 -1.2534511    14            Druze
11 -0.1625003    31         Mozabite
12 -1.0265275    35      Palestinian
13 -0.8519079     2          Balochi
14 -2.4279528     8           Brahui
15 -3.1717421     9          Burusho
16 -0.9258497    17           Hazara
17 -1.2207974    21           Kalash
18 -1.0325107    24          Makrani
19 -3.2102686    37           Pathan
20 -0.9377928    43           Sindhi
21 -1.7657017    48           Uygurf
22 -0.5058627    10        Cambodian
23 -0.7819299    12              Dai
24 -1.4095947    13             Daur
25  2.2810477    16              Han
26 -0.9007551    18           Hezhen
27  2.6614486    20         Japanese
28 -0.9441980    23             Lahu
29 -0.7237586    29             Miao
30 -0.9452944    30          Mongola
31 -1.2035258    32             Naxi
32 -0.7703779    34           Oroqen
33 -3.0895998    42              She
34 -0.7037952    45               Tu
35 -1.9311354    46            Tujia
36 -0.5423822    49             Xibo
37 -1.6244801    50            Yakut
38 -0.9049735    51               Yi
39 -2.6491331    11        Colombian
40  2.3706977    22        Karitiana
41 -2.7590587    26             Maya
42 -0.9614190    38             Pima
43 -1.6961014    44            Surui
44 -0.8449225    28       Melanesian
45 -1.1163019    36           Papuan
46 -0.9298674     3       BantuKenya
47 -2.8859587     4 BantuSouthAfrica
48 -1.4494841     7       BiakaPygmy
49 -0.7381369    25         Mandenka
50 -0.5644325    27       MbutiPygmy
51 -0.9195156    40              San
52  2.0949378    52           Yoruba
```

I would like to graph the column `gvs` along the x-axis in the order of the column `order`, and then have the label for each point along the x-axis to be from the column `labels`. Does anyone know how this is done? I want the graph to look like a less colorful version of the graphs in figure-5 in this paper http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1004412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like (1) `labels` doesn't correspond to `gvs` and `order`, and (2) if I sort the first two columns by `order`, the data frame will be ordered properly. Please let me know if this is not correct.

Sort first two columns by `order`, leaving third column alone:

```
df[,c("gvs","order")] = df[order(df$order), c("gvs","order")]
```

Set the ordering of `labels` based on the current ordering of `labels` in the sample data frame:

```
df$labels = factor(df$labels, levels=df$labels)
```

Add a grouping variable for region. I did this by creating a new group each time the alphabetic ordering of `labels` went "backwards". The regions are just numbers here, but you can give them descriptive names if you want to use them:

```
df$group = c(0, cumsum(diff(match(substr(df$labels,1,1), LETTERS)) < 0))
```

Add fake p-values (since point size was based on p-value in the graph you linked to):

```
set.seed(595)
df$p.value = runif(nrow(df), 0, 0.5)
```

Plot the data, including a different color for each regional group, point-size based on p-value, and black borders around points with p < 0.05. `geom_line` add the regional means:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df, aes(labels, gvs, size=p.value, fill=factor(group))) + 
  geom_line(data=df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(gvs=mean(gvs)),
            aes(group=group, colour=factor(group)), size=0.8,alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(pch=21, stroke=1, aes(color=p.value<0.05)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, hjust=0, vjust=0.5),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank()) +
  scale_size_continuous(name="p values", limits=c(0, 0.5), breaks=seq(0,1,0.1), range=c(4,1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(hcl(seq(15,375,length.out=8),100,65)[1:7],NA,"black")) +
  labs(x="Language", fill="Region") +
  guides(colour=FALSE, 
         size=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE, override.aes=list(color=NA,fill="grey50")),
         fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE, override.aes=list(color=NA, size=3)))
```

[image]

Comment: oops, added the link, going to try this out now! thanks

Comment: I'm confused on what the output is in this, I work in terminal so I've never been good at visualizing the ggplots

Comment: Can't you just look at the plot?

Comment: I'm in terminal so I just see: http://imgur.com/a/kTO9d. Is there a way to get a .jpg file output?

Comment: I'd suggest using `RStudio`, which will make it much easier to see the ouput of your code. For now, see update, which includes code to save the graph.

Comment: Thanks so much! We are very close! Here is what the file looked like: http://imgur.com/a/NN0Et. I want the x-axis to be in the order given in the original data.frame thought. The only thing that needs to be ordered by the `order` column is the `gvs` along the x-axis. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ordering by the `order` column means that the first value on the x-axis will have order=1 (Adygei), the second value will have order=2 (Balochi), etc. Do you mean you want the `label` values to be in the same order as in the data you posted (i.e., Adygei, Basque, etc.)? That's fine, but it's different from ordering by `order`.

Comment: Yes I want the values in the left column `gvs` to be ordered by the order column. But the values in the `labels` column I want to be in the order that they already are in the original data.frame. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Should the graph look exactly the same as before? Here's the new graph: http://imgur.com/a/1dgDW. I want the `gvs` plotted along the x-axis in the order described in the order column. I want the labels plotted in the same order they appear in the labels column. Is that what this new graph is? Shouldn't the old plot look the same as the new plot if the `gvs` were always plotted in the order of `order` column. The only difference should be the x-axis right?

Comment: Now I'm really confused. Are you saying you want to break the link between the `gvs` column and the `labels` column by sorting them separately? Maybe you should list, say, the first five labels on the x-axis  and the first five y-values that should be in the plot (both starting from the left), just to be absolutely clear.

Comment: First point = (Adygei, -2.33), second point from left = (Basque, -0.85), third point from left (French, -0.93), fourth point from left = (italian, -2.89)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117864/discussion-between-evan-and-eipi10).

Answer (score 1):

Read data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(gvs = c(-2.3321916, -1.4996229, 1.795817, 2.5543214, -2.775846, -1.9659984, 
                      2.1239768, -1.8515908, -1.5597359, -1.2534511, -0.1625003, -1.0265275, 
                      -0.8519079, -2.4279528, -3.1717421, -0.9258497, -1.2207974, -1.0325107, 
                      -3.2102686, -0.9377928, -1.7657017, -0.5058627, -0.7819299, -1.4095947, 
                      2.2810477, -0.9007551, 2.6614486, -0.944198, -0.7237586, -0.9452944, 
                      -1.2035258, -0.7703779, -3.0895998, -0.7037952, -1.9311354, -0.5423822, 
                      -1.6244801, -0.9049735, -2.6491331, 2.3706977, -2.7590587, -0.961419, 
                      -1.6961014, -0.8449225, -1.1163019, -0.9298674, -2.8859587, -1.4494841, 
                      -0.7381369, -0.5644325, -0.9195156, 2.0949378),
             order = c(1L, 5L, 15L, 19L, 33L, 39L, 41L, 47L, 6L, 14L, 31L, 35L, 2L, 
                       8L, 9L, 17L, 21L, 24L, 37L, 43L, 48L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 
                       20L, 23L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 34L, 42L, 45L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 11L, 
                       22L, 26L, 38L, 44L, 28L, 36L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 25L, 27L, 40L, 52L),
             labels = c("Adygei", "Basque", "French", "Italian", "Orcadian", "Russian", 
                        "Sardinian", "Tuscan", "Bedouin", "Druze", "Mozabite", "Palestinian", 
                        "Balochi", "Brahui", "Burusho", "Hazara", "Kalash", "Makrani", 
                        "Pathan", "Sindhi", "Uygurf", "Cambodian", "Dai", "Daur", "Han", 
                        "Hezhen", "Japanese", "Lahu", "Miao", "Mongola", "Naxi", "Oroqen", 
                        "She", "Tu", "Tujia", "Xibo", "Yakut", "Yi", "Colombian", "Karitiana", 
                        "Maya", "Pima", "Surui", "Melanesian", "Papuan", "BantuKenya", 
                        "BantuSouthAfrica", "BiakaPygmy", "Mandenka", "MbutiPygmy", "San", 
                        "Yoruba"))
```

Order data

```
df.ordered <- df[ order(df$order) , ]
```

And some simple (ugly) sample plotting which you can surely improve upon (maybe with ggplot)

```
plot(df.ordered$gvs, pch = 19)
axis(1, at=1:52, labels=df.ordered$labels, las=2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close, but I want the x-axis labels to come in the order that it already is in the data.frame

Comment: I'm confused about your comment: in the original post you say " would like to graph the column gvs along the x-axis in the order of the column order, and then have the label for each point along the x-axis to be from the column labels". It so happens that the order in the column "order", is also what orders the labels alphabeta-ically.

Comment: I want the gvs column to be in the order of the order column, but I want the x-axis to remain how in the order that it is in the data.frame, does that make sense?

Comment: So like I want the exact same graph that you produced, except somehow make the x-axis labels in the order of the original file

Comment: That's no problem. Just change the axis argument: axis(1, at=1:52, labels=df$labels, las=2).

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you take a look at the newest question I just posted?

Answer (score 1):

Another option that doesn't rely on the sorting of the dataframe is to use the `limits` parameter of a discrete scale (which as a side benefit can allow you do do more arbitrary ordering when plotting.)

```
df <-read.csv(/path/to/file/df.csv')

xorder <-df[order(df$order),'labels']
ggplot(df, aes(x=labels, y=gvs, size=gvs)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=xorder)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90))
```

Comment: This is very close but the x-axis labels are showing up alphabetically and I want them in the order shown in the data.frame